# No route matches [DELETE] "/" ; ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, partials

The objective is to remove an item; I get the impression the error is in my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:show, :destroy]
  resources :items, only: [:new, :index, :create, :destroy]
  resources :welcome, only: [:index]
  get 'items/new'    
  root 'items#index'
end
```

The partial is the following:

```
<p><%= item.name %></p>
<%= link_to "Done!", root_path, method: :delete, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok' %>
```

And just in case, the following is the destroy action in my items_controller:

```
  def destroy
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])

    if @item.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "You accomplished a task!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error deleting the task. Try again."
    end
  end
```

As mentioned earlier, I get the impression it's my routes, though I have been tinkering with them for a while. Does anyone see what I have misconstrued?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use the root path, you should use the item path

Comment: you need the item path for the specific item you are deleting.  so item_path(`@item`) i think?

Comment: i would give the answer to @Hamms his is the more complete answer... maybe i should stop trying answer questions from my phone...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `:destroy` defines a [`DELETE` route for `/:id`, not for `/`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions). You can only delete *something* not everything.

Your `link_to` should link to the delete path for the *specific item*, not to `root_path` or to the items index:

```
<%= link_to "Done!", item, method: :delete, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok' %>
```

Comment: Changed it to this and it worked:
<%= link_to "Done!", **item_path(item)**, method: :delete, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok' %>
Thank you so much!